# Azure databricks msal library python 2 instead of python 3

Tags: python, azure-ad-msal, azure-databricks

I installed the current wheel library of msal from the official [pypi repository](https://pypi.org/project/msal/).
But the wheel file has a python version of v2.
I try to install this library into my Azure Databricks Cluster where python 3 is configured. This conflicts because the wheel library of msal has python 2 configured. The library installed perfectly when I downgraded the Databricks cluster to python 2. But that can't be the solution because all my notebooks are programmed in python 3. I also can't think of any idea why the msal library isn't already in python 3 ?
Any workaround for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have been resolved since [MSAL 0.9.0](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/releases/tag/0.9.0) or above.

Disclosure: I'm one of the maintainers of that library.